# How to remove newlines and indents from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

In my Python script, I have a SQL statement that goes on forever like so:

```
query = """
    SELECT * FROM
        many_many
        tables
    WHERE
        this = that,
        a_bunch_of = other_conditions
"""
```

What's the best way to get this to read like a single line? I tried this:

```
def formattedQuery(query):
    lines = query.split('\n')

    for line in lines:
        line = line.lstrip()
        line = line.rstrip()

    return ' '.join(lines)
```

and it did remove newlines but not spaces from the indents. Please help!

Comment: Did you tried something like `query.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
query = " ".join(query.split())
```

but it will not work very well if your SQL queries contain strings with spaces or tabs (for example `select * from users where name = 'Jura   X'`). This is a problem of other solutions which use `string.replace` or regular expressions. So your approach is not too bad, but your code needs to be fixed.

What is actually wrong with your function - you return the original, the return values of lsplit and rsplit are abandoned. You could fix it like this:

```
def formattedQuery(query):
  lines = query.split('\n')
  r = []

  for line in lines:
    line = line.lstrip()
    line = line.rstrip()
    r.append(line)

  return ' '.join(r)
```

Another way of doing it:

```
def formattedQuery(q): return " ".join([s.strip() for s in q.splitlines()])
```

Comment: Gah, that was dumb. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another one line:

```
>>> import re

>>> re.sub(r'\s', ' ', query)

'SELECT * FROM many_many tables WHERE this = that, a_bunch_of = other_conditions'
```

This replaces all white spaces characters in the string `query` by a single `' '` white space.

Answer (score 0):

string.translate can remove characters (just provide None for the second argument so it doesn't also convert characters):

```
import string
string.translate(query, None, "\n\t")
```

Comment: Removed in python 3

Comment: The same can be achieved in python3 with `query.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "\n\t"))`. The third argument to `maketrans` is a last of characters which will be mapped to `None` and so squished.